# Weird cursor glitch in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image]

This weird text cursor glitch just happened to me in Visual Studio where instead of the normal text cursor it replaced it with a gray blinking cursor that is super buggy. Instead of working like a normal text cursor, it deletes/replaces the character behind the selected character when I delete that letter. So for example (using the picture above), it would delete the a instead of deleting the highlighted letter, which is m. It's really hard to explain but this cursor is super buggy and weird. I don't know if this is a bug or a keybind that I accidentally triggered

Comment: Press the "Insert"/"Ins" key on your keyboard to toggle that on and off

Answer (score 0):

Press "insert"/"ins" key from your keyboard. Sometimes you need to click Fn + "insert" key.